# iPhone Core Data Recursive relationship

Tags: iphone, core-data, entity-relationship, relationship

I try to create a recursive relationship in core data.
I have a Model "MenuItem" that can contains some other "MenuItem", it reference itself in a too-many-relationship. To do that a created a "children" too-many-relationship, and a "parent" relationship. The both relationship are inverse of the other one. 
But when i try to compile a get this error :

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_MenuItem in /Users/mlecomte/Dropbox/Projects/iPhone/Emakina/Electrabel/XCode/build/Electrabel.build/Debug-iphoneos/Electrabel.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MenuItem-FA48D8B96953EA4D.o and /Users/mlecomte/Dropbox/Projects/iPhone/Emakina/Electrabel/XCode/build/Electrabel.build/Debug-iphoneos/Electrabel.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MenuItem-FD173522ABE19C3D.o
>
> Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

EDIT: I forget to say that i generated the Object Managed class of the menuitem.

when i delete the relationship or when i dont generate the Object Managed class for menuItem everything compile juste fine.

I will thank you in advance for your help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seems that you have 2 MenuItem classes. Delete all of them and recreate them from menu.
And also delete the old app and then rebuild.

Comment: Thanks, your right. I used an external lib that already had an MenuItem classe.